# VBA Excel match or find substring

Tags: excel, vba

Quick example:

```
    A      B       C      D      E      F
1          
2                 str1   str2   str3   str4
```

I want to store the first range-object, in row 2, with `str` as the first three characters of the cell.

Is this possible in VBA?

This is what I am trying to achieve:

```
Dim rng As Range
Dim colNr as integer
colNr = WorksheetFunction.Match(left(cell.value,3)="str", .range("2:2"), 0)
set rng = Sheets("Sheet1").cells(2,colNr)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are pretty close:

```
Dim rng As Range
Dim colNr as Long
With Sheets("Sheet1")
    colNr = WorksheetFunction.Match("str*", .range("2:2"), 0)
    set rng = .cells(2,colNr)
End With
```

Answer (score 0):

Fundamentally I would use a `For Each ... In ... Next` loop and interrupt on first find. Here's a working draft without too much error checking (TargetRange is only 1 row, TargetCell is a string, UCase/LCase, etc ...):

```
Function FirstMatch(TargetRange As Range, SearchString As String) As Variant
Dim TargetCell As Range

    ' if we don't find any, we return  a #N/A error value
    FirstMatch = CVErr(xlErrNA)

    For Each TargetCell In TargetRange.Cells
        If InStr(1, TargetCell, SearchString) Then
            ' returning the value of first find
            ' FirstMatch = TargetCell

            ' returning the column position relative to the first cell in selected range
            FirstMatch = TargetCell.Column - TargetRange(1, 1).Column + 1
            Exit Function
        End If
    Next TargetCell

End Function
```

usage for your case would be:

A2: `=FirstMatch(C2:F2, "str")`

Modify the `If ...` condition as per your need (e.g `Left(...)` etc.)

Using a function you avoid hard coding (*bad bad bad*)!

**A word of caution**: Allthough `For Each ... In ... Next` [doesn't guarantee a strictly sequential processing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5ebk1751%28VS.80%29.aspx) I always found it rather safe when used with 1-dimentional ranges of moderate sizes. If you want to be absolutely sure you need to introduce an index variable and use a plain `For ... Next` loop.